# How many times does the following occur SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to find out each different number that has the system outcome no_answer more than 5 times

Does any one know how to find the following i.e

```
Table Name Calls

Field 1 - Phone_number
Field 2 - System_outcome

Phone_number      System_outcome
07777778999       Answered
07777778123       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778999       No Answer
07777778124       No Answer
07777778128       Answered
07777778074       Answered
```

Comment: Hint:  `GROUP BY`, `HAVING`.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Phone_number, COUNT(*) AS no_answer_count
FROM Calls
WHERE System_outcome = 'no_answer'
GROUP BY Phone_number
HAVING no_answer_count > 5
```

Comment: Note that the 'WHERE' clause must go before the 'GROUP BY', contrary to one of the earlier responses.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use combination of group by and having with where condition

```
select Phone_number 
from Calls
where System_outcome='No Answer'
group by Phone_number      
having count(Phone_number) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

You can `group by` phone number and filter those `having` count greater than 5

```
select phone_number
from Calls
where System_outcome = 'No Answer'
group by phone_number
having count(*) > 5;
```

Comment: having count(*) > 5; - how do i specify just one system_outcome?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT phone_number
FROM Calls
WHERE System_outcome='No Answer'
GROUP BY phone_number
HAVING count(Phone_number) > 5;
```